# Is a strictly decreasing, invertible function necessarily continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We know that the inverse exists (therefore injective and surjective), and it is strictly decreasing. I'm not sure if continuity follows.

Comment: What are the domain and range?

Comment: For functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$, you might want to use the fact that the only types of discontinuities that a monotone function can have are jump discontinuities.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it necessarily follows. For example the split function:

$f: [-3;3] \rightarrow [-3;-1]\cup[0;4]$,

$f(x)= \mathrm{if}(x<1, -x+1, -x)$.

It is discontinuous at $x=1$, but it is still invertible and strictly decreasing.